# Intercepting hibernate initialization

Tags: hibernate

I am working on a spl that its ORM is Hibernate.
I want to when another programmer request from hibernate to load an entity, if that entity is a logical deleted entity hibernate doesn't initialize that field.

(for example: Entity has a field that named delete. delete:1 for delete. And delete:0 for alive)

More explanation:
I want when I load an entity by `Session.load(...)` and return it. When client which is another programmer gets a property that is in lazy mode before that hibernate initializes it, We check if that property is an aggregation and is deleted as logical hibernate or myself return null instead of that deleted property.

Comment: I think maybe you should try to explain a little more about *what* you want to achieve, then maybe someone can provide an explanation of *how* to do it. From your question it sounds like you are trying to implement a hack, and that *maybe* you could achieve what you want with the correct locking strategy and transaction isolation level. Just maybe ...